# Работа по ЧПУ сайта. Удалить папку из адреса

Tags: чпу

Есть сайт на MODX Revolution 2.6.5, нужно провести работы по ЧПУ. Суть в том что адрес выглядит примерно так https://www.site/products/uslugi/, а мне нужно чтобы он выглядел так: https://www.site/uslugi/ Т.е. нужно убрать из адреса /products/. Заморозка URI в админке не помогает, проблема еще в том что нужные страницы лежат в контейнере (в админке), который служит левым меню на сайте. Если страницы оттуда убрать, соответственно меню рассыпется. Нашел в статье про редиректы такой способ: Удаляем «category» из URL - RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L], но он не работает. Что еще можно придумать даже не представляю.

Answer (score 0):

Можете обновиться до 2.7.1? Если да, рекомендую попробовать вот такую относительно свежую фичу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Использовать псевдоним в пути псевдонимов*(alias_visible) поле.